# regex search in vs2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

How can I perform a case insensitive search that will find two words that may or may not have a space between them in Visual Studio 2010 e.g.

Foo Bar

FooBar

fooBar

foo bar

EDIT:

Sorry I should have been clearer - I mean a ctrl+shift+f (Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files) search in VS2010 - I don't want to implement this in code - I want to find code/comments etc that matches the search criteria above.

I could also just do four searches... but I am interested to know how to do this in one go, and I would feel more comfortable doing it in one go as I am refactoring.

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex:

foo:b*bar

In VS search form:
[image]

In code Regex has a case sensitivity option.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a single regular expression, but I believe the code will be more readable if you handle each case seprately. Check if the string looks like "FooBar" (maybe using a regex), and if it doesn't, just count the number of spaces in the string (you can use `Trim()`) to eliminate the leading and training spaces).